# Git repo referencing other repos

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Link 1 git repository to some other repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377573/how-to-link-1-git-repository-to-some-other-repositories)

i'm developing a game, which will work in different platforms, say Android and Desktop, i have two repos for that, and a third repo for the game logic, what i wanna do is to reference the core repo in the Android and Desktop repo, then when i do a pull, in the Android repo for example, it will download the Android code and the core logic of the game, i'm really new in git, and the posts about this are a little confusing for me.
So is there a way to do that?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377573/how-to-link-1-git-repository-to-some-other-repositories

Answer (score 0):

We use Tortoise Git, and what we do is manually pull that submodule, when we are ready to deploy.  But we only have one submodule, and it's not vital.

I would suggest taking a look at this link.  I think there are numerous solutions for you here:

[Easy way pull latest of all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/git-easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules)