# Direct link/access of a githib repos from another github account?

Tags: github

This might be a naive question. I have couple of repos on my github account (say on account A). For the purpose of publications I should push my projects to someone else's github account (account B) and provide the other repos link in the publication.

I would like to (1) keep the credit of my codes even when repos are in his account, (2) do not update account B if repos in A changed. Account B will not do any development on code, and only its used for providing it's URL in publications.

My question is that, is there anyway to have a direct link from my repos in account B to account A? I think with fetching or a basic mirroring, account B should keep updating the original repos regularly, but I want to avoid it.

What I want is either:

1) a direct link that when clients click on it on account B, they will be directed to my repos on account A. 
2) or if the above is not possible, by cloning from account B, clients get files directly from repos on account A.

Any ideas if it (or anything similar to it) is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has something for this exact thing - it's called [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).  From the Git website:

> Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

Check out the answer to this question - it has a bit more detail (credit to @Jefromi): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377799/1442788